# Stack overflow when composing functions in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

Basically, my problem is that I'm trying to compose a very large number of functions, so I'm creating a deep chain of composed functions. Here is my code:

```
let rec fn (f : (State -> State option) -> (State -> State option)) (n : int) acc =
    match n with 
    | 0 -> acc 
    | _ -> fn f (n - 1) (f << acc)
```

and I make a call to it:

```
let foo = fn id 10000000 id bottom
```

So, it does ten milion iteration and it should combining lots of functions.
I know for sure that `fn` is tail recursive (at least, I hope so), but the execution goes stack overflow and I can't figure out why.

At this point, the problem should be the deep cobination. So I was hoping for suggestions, tips, everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BrianBerns's answer explains what's going on here, but I'd like to add a possible remedy.

Rather than using an `acc` variable to accumulate the monstrous composition of functions, take the seed argument and actually apply the function at every step:

```
let rec fn (f : (State -> State option) -> (State -> State option)) (n : int) arg =
    match n with 
    | 0 -> arg
    | _ -> fn f (n - 1) (f arg)
```

The meaning of this function is the same as your original: it applies function `f` to `arg` `n` times.

It is still tail-recursive, but it doesn't build up a big chain of composed functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem becomes a lot clearer if you split `foo` into two steps:

```ml
let bar = fn id 10000000 id   // create huge chain of functions (this works)
let foo = bar bottom          // execute huge chain of functions (this goes boom!)
```

So `fn` is indeed tail recursive and it successfully executes, creating a mega-function of chained functions that I've called `bar`. However, `bar` is *not* tail recursive, so when you call it with `bottom`, it exhausts the stack.

Update: Since `bar` is `fun x -> f (f (f ... f (acc x)))`, I think you'd be better off evaluating `acc bottom` directly (before calling the recursive function), rather than delaying `acc` by sending it to `fn`. (This is essentially what Fyodor is suggesting as well.)